# Notification Hub RegistrationAuthorizationException

Tags: azure, push-notification, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app, azure-notificationhub

I followed this [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-windows-store-dotnet-get-started/#configure-your-notification-hub) yesterday to receive notification from azure notification hub on my windows 8.1 phone app and it was working but

But today it is throwing me this error

```
An exception of type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Messaging.RegistrationAuthorizationException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: HTTP request failed.



HTTP Details:

Status: 401

Reason: Unauthorized

Full content: <Error><Code>401</Code><Detail>ExpiredToken: .TrackingId:e27f22fb-5c9c-4028-8594-eacb71e5a35e_G1,TimeStamp:4/14/2016 10:29:33 AM</Detail></Error>
```

It is throwing this exception in the `InitNotificationsAsync` method in my App.xaml.cs when my app is trying to register

```
private async void InitNotificationsAsync()
    {
        var channel = await PushNotificationChannelManager.CreatePushNotificationChannelForApplicationAsync();

        var hub = new NotificationHub("nameofhub", "myconnectionstring");
        var result = await hub.RegisterNativeAsync(channel.Uri);

        //Displays the registration ID so you know it was successful
        if (result.RegistrationId != null)
        {
            var dialog = new MessageDialog("Registration successful: " + result.RegistrationId);
            dialog.Commands.Add(new UICommand("OK"));
            await dialog.ShowAsync();
        }

    }
```

Comment: which service are you using on Azure? If it is the new App Service container you are using then you should follow this instead: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-windows-store-dotnet-get-started-push/

Answer (score 0):

Do you try it in the emulator or..? 
It can be the time syncronization. 
If that is the emulator, can you check the time and set it up manually?

Comment: I uninstalled the app from emulator and the deployed again and was working fine but a few hours later same thing happened

Comment: It is starting to looks like it is not the time issue, but could you please check the local machine time and the emulator time? It is not clear from your response. Did you try to deploy it to the real device and see how it is going?

Comment: I would like to add to my first comment that I also had to close the emulator and start it again

Comment: Could you please you set the time in the emulator manually to eliminate the possibility of the time issue?

Comment: Sorry they were same it was showing 12:58 in emulator and here it is 00:58 but I went into the app and saw it was 12:58 am so time is not an issue